# How to clean up the Spark completed applications instances from the Spark master Web url

Tags: apache-spark

can anyone please let me know how to delete the Spark completed applications from the Spark master url?

Comment: can you elaborate more ? one liner questions cant help you.

Answer (score 0):

More properties on History server cleaner can be found here:https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact